# Contacts first and last name order inconsistent between iCloud.com and iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts, icloud

The iCloud.com Contacts interface orders the name fields as following: Last name, First name

On the iPhone, the order is reversed: First name, Last name.

Can this be adjusted so the order matches?

Comment: Please do a Google search before asking questions for simple stuff.

Comment: I tried Google first. Before adding such comments it would be good to provide link at least.

Answer (score 2):

- For the iPhone you can adjust the order of fields in Preferences -> Mail, Contacts, Calendar
- For iCloud you can do the same by opening the Contacts web app and selecting Preferences (cog wheel in the lower left corner)